# Go to slide based on data attribute in Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

Some slides in my slick slider have data attributes such as this: `data-artwork="unique-id"`. What I'm trying to do is when you `hover` over a menu item it will `slickGoTo` a slide based on the data-attribute.

The menu items have matching data-attributes like this:

```
<ul class="project-feed">
    <li data-artwork="unique-id">
        <a href="#">Example</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I'm using Javascript to add those data-attributes to a variable, like so:

```
$('.project-feed li').hover(function() {
    var artworkId = $(this).data('artwork'); // 'unique-id'
});
```

My question is how can I then use slick slider to go to the relative slide? Ex: If I hover over a menu item with `data-artwork="test"` then it will go to the slide with the same `data-artwork` value.

**For extra credit:** How can I then resume the slider from where it left off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
    var resumeIndex;
    $('.project-feed li').hover(function() {
        resumeIndex = $slider.slick("getSlick").currentSlide;
        var artworkId = $(this).data('artwork');
        var artIndex = $slider.find('[data-artwork="' + artworkId + '"]').data('slick-index');
        $slider.slick('slickPause').slick('slickGoTo', artIndex);
        console.log(resumeIndex);
    }, function() {
        $slider.slick('slickGoTo', 0).slick('slickPlay');
    });
```

But it's unpredictable. If you hover through the menu too quickly it behaves badly and gets confused.

**Edit:**

Adding a delay onto the hover (in) helped smooth out the functionality:

```
    var randomSlide;
    var timeout;

    $('.project-feed li').hover(function() {
        var artworkId = $(this).data('artwork');
        var artIndex = $slider.find('[data-artwork="' + artworkId + '"]').data('slick-index');
        var totalSlides = $('.slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned)').length;
        randomSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * totalSlides) + 1);

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $slider.slick('slickPause').slick('slickGoTo', artIndex);
        }, 500);

    }, function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $slider.slick('slickGoTo', randomSlide).slick('slickPlay');
    });
```